# time to spend look for location using NETWORK_PROVIDER

Tags: android, gps, location, android-contentprovider

I need to find location of the user in my app, and to see if he close to some specific places.
first I try to check if he close to those places by NETWORK_PROVIDER (to save battery power), and just if the answer is positive I use GPS to find accurate location. 
How long worthwhile try to find a place through NETWORK_PROVIDER before I decide whether to use also GPS?
eg, after 1 sec or 20, the devise likely succeed to find location using network?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is really difficult to tell, I would suggest using Google play services location api instead. You can't know for sure if first received location is even remotely accurate, especially with network based that is useless in places where Google have no wifi ssid-location match.

Comment: Hi, how Google play services help me? as I read, they dont let this option, but strait try to get location by GPS.
and about your last sentence - I never saw this problem when I read about network provider. can you give me source for this? thanks

Comment: This API uses its own logic to determine user location. Google devices automatically sends to servers their location in a certain time manner. I assume google play services uses that information. Check 'fused location provider' https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/location.html

Comment: I dont sure what is this "certain time" but yesterday I turn on the GPS in my device and I saw it didnt take location 30 at least minutes, although I drove in my car, so my place changed, so it dont help me, in my app, because I need to take place all 5 minutes.
and about your last sentence "especially with network based..." - I never saw this problem when I read about network provider. can you give me source for this? thanks